# Ocultar e mostrar div utilizando href

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber como ocultar e mostrar div utilizando href?
Por exemplo, tenho um Titulo chamado "Filtro" ao clica no botão ao lado dele, quero que mostre os elementos que estão dentro dele e ao clicar novamente quero que oculte os elementos.

```html
<div class="widget boxed">
  <div class="widget-head">
    <h4 class="pull-left">
      <i class="icon-reorder"></i>Filtros
    </h4>
    <div id="filtro" class="widget-icons pull-right">
      <a href="#" class="wminimize"><i class="fa-angle-double-down"></i> </a>
      <!-- ocultrar nesse aqui-->
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-content" style="display: none;">
    <!--pra esconder isso -->
```

Comment: Podes mostrar a estrutura do teu HTML?

Comment: <div class="widget boxed">
                <div class="widget-head">
                    <h4 class="pull-left">
                        <i class="icon-reorder"></i>Filtros
                    </h4>
                    <div id="filtro"class="widget-icons pull-right">
                        <a href="#"  class="wminimize"><i class="fa-angle-double-down"></i> </a> <!-- ocultrar nesse aqui-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="widget-content" style="display: none;"><!--pra esconder isso -->

Comment: Diego, coloquei o HTML dos comentários na pergunta, ainda não percebi qual a parte que deve ser escondida ao carregar onde. Podes clicar em [edit] e explicar melhor?

Comment: Não consigo colocar o codigo todo é muito grande.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu href vai ficar da seguinte maneira:

```
<a href="javascript:ocultarMostrarFiltros()" class="wminimize">
```

Agora você precisa ter a função que faz a mágica :

Primeiro você verifica o estado atual ( caso seja do seu interesse se não pode apenas ocultar ou mostrar diretamente ) e armazena em uma variável.

```
function ocultarMostrarFiltros(){
    var visivel = document.getElementsByClassName("example").style.display;
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
    if(visivel == 'none'){
        element.style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        element.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Se quiser deixar com um tom mais agradável você pode usar o jQuery com a função hide() e show() ou simplesmente trabalhar com transition no seu css.
Espero ter ajudado! até a próxima.

Answer (score 0):

Pode criar uma função do JavaScript:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

Você deve chamar a função dentro do Título: `onclick="myFunction()"`